# Fast serialization/deserialization of structs

Tags: c#, performance, serialization, struct

I have huge amont of geographic data represented in simple object structure consisting only structs. All of my fields are of value type.

```
public struct Child
{
   readonly float X;
   readonly float Y;
   readonly int myField;
}

public struct Parent
{
   readonly int id;
   readonly int field1;
   readonly int field2;
   readonly Child[] children;
}
```

The data is chunked up nicely to small portions of `Parent[]`-s. Each array contains a few thousands Parent instances. I have way too much data to keep all in memory, so I need to swap these chunks to disk back and forth. (One file would result approx. 2-300KB).

What would be the most efficient way of serializing/deserializing the `Parent[]` to a `byte[]` for dumpint to disk and reading back? Concerning speed, **I am particularly interested in fast deserialization**, write speed is not that critical.

Would simple `BinarySerializer` good enough?
Or should I hack around with [`StructLayout` (see accepted answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3563830/converting-system-decimal-to-system-guid)? I am not sure if that would work with array field of `Parent.children`.

UPDATE: Response to comments - Yes, the objects are immutable (code updated) and indeed the `children` field is not value type. 300KB sounds not much but I have zillions of files like that, so speed does matter.

Comment: _All of my fields are of value type_ - The `children` field is not a value type.

Comment: 300KB is small amount, this amount is deserialized/serialized in 0.1s w/o optimizations

Comment: The binary serializer is very slow. It uses reflection to inject metadata into the serialization data. Becuase it doesn't provide type-metadata, the XML serializer serializes data in a much smaller and faster format than the binary serializer. In either case, the serialization is done via reflection and is very slow. One of my brilliant coworkers created a custom binary serialization mechanism that was 20 times faster than the XML serializer, which was faster than the binary serializer. It was also signicantly smaller.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

BinarySerializer is a very general serializer. It will not perform as well as a custom implementation.

Fortunately for your, your data consists of structs only. This means that you will be able to fix a structlayout for Child and just bit-copy the children array using unsafe code from a byte[] you have read from disk.

For the parents it is not that easy because you need to treat the children separately. I recommend you use unsafe code to copy the bit-copyable fields from the byte[] you read and deserialize the children separately.

Did you consider mapping all the children into memory using memory mapped files? You could then re-use the operating systems cache facility and not deal with reading and writing at all.

Zero-copy-deserializing a Child[] looks like this:

```
byte[] bytes = GetFromDisk();
fixed (byte* bytePtr = bytes) {
 Child* childPtr = (Child*)bytePtr;
 //now treat the childPtr as an array:
 var x123 = childPtr[123].X;

 //if we need a real array that can be passed around, we need to copy:
 var childArray = new Child[GetLengthOfDeserializedData()];
 for (i = [0..length]) {
  childArray[i] = childPtr[i];
 }
}
```

Comment: I looked up memory mapped files, they look great for disk access management! Could you write an example for the unsafe segment? How can I "cast" a byte[] to a Child[] in unsafe mode? Because as you said it would take zero time.

Comment: I added an example. If you want zero-copy you need to change your app to use pointers or unsafe IO using ReadFile (directly read into an existing Child[]). But my guess is that the single pass of copying is really nothing. CPUs are good at that.

Answer (score 14):

If you don't fancy going down the *write your own serializer* route, you can use the [protobuf.net](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/) serializer. Here's the output from a small test program:

> ```
> Using 3000 parents, each with 5 children
> BinaryFormatter Serialized in: 00:00:00.1250000
> Memory stream 486218 B
> BinaryFormatter Deserialized in: 00:00:00.1718750
>
> ProfoBuf Serialized in: 00:00:00.1406250
> Memory stream 318247 B
> ProfoBuf Deserialized in: 00:00:00.0312500
> ```

It should be fairly self-explanatory. This was just for one run, but was fairly indicative of the speed up I saw (3-5x).

To make your structs serializable (with protobuf.net), just add the following attributes:

```
[ProtoContract]
[Serializable]
public struct Child
{
    [ProtoMember(1)] public float X;
    [ProtoMember(2)] public float Y;
    [ProtoMember(3)] public int myField;
}

[ProtoContract]
[Serializable]
public struct Parent
{
    [ProtoMember(1)] public int id;
    [ProtoMember(2)] public int field1;
    [ProtoMember(3)] public int field2;
    [ProtoMember(4)] public Child[] children;
}
```

UPDATE:

Actually, writing a custom serializer is pretty easy, here is a bare-bones implementation:

```
class CustSerializer
{
    public void Serialize(Stream stream, Parent[] parents, int childCount)
    {
        BinaryWriter sw = new BinaryWriter(stream);
        foreach (var parent in parents)
        {
            sw.Write(parent.id);
            sw.Write(parent.field1);
            sw.Write(parent.field2);

            foreach (var child in parent.children)
            {
                sw.Write(child.myField);
                sw.Write(child.X);
                sw.Write(child.Y);
            }
        }
    }

    public Parent[] Deserialize(Stream stream, int parentCount, int childCount)
    {
        BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(stream);
        Parent[] parents = new Parent[parentCount];

        for (int i = 0; i < parentCount; i++)
        {
            var parent = new Parent();
            parent.id = br.ReadInt32();
            parent.field1 = br.ReadInt32();
            parent.field2 = br.ReadInt32();
            parent.children = new Child[childCount];

            for (int j = 0; j < childCount; j++)
            {
                var child = new Child();
                child.myField = br.ReadInt32();
                child.X = br.ReadSingle();
                child.Y = br.ReadSingle();
                parent.children[j] = child;
            }

            parents[i] = parent;
        }
        return parents;
    }
}
```

And here is its output when run in a simple speed test:

> ```
> Custom Serialized in: 00:00:00 
> Memory stream 216000 B 
> Custom Deserialized in: 00:00:00.0156250
> ```

Obviously, it's a lot less flexible than the other approaches, but if speed really is that important it's about 2-3x faster than the protobuf method. It produces minimal file sizes as well, so writing to disk should be faster.

Comment: Protobuf is a great trade-off between ease of use and performance in most cases. If you want to go nuts it still can't beat the performance of a custom solution. Especially a bit-blittable one which can have a cost of exactly zero!

Comment: shouldn't you have checked whether or not its a 64x machine or a x32 one?